# matlab assign a "export settings" -> "load settings from" for figures programmatically

Tags: matlab

I have some figure styles I have saved in the "export settings" dialog that is accessed under File->"Export Setup".

Is there a way to load one of my styles programmatically?  ie.  I currently need to do a number of mouse clicks to load my desired style, then apply it to the figure, then tell it to export and give the file a name.    I feel like all this should be doable through a few commands but I can't find the right information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this solution at the bottom of [this thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/152026):

```
 % create an example fig that we want to format with style file 'foo'
 plot(rand(14,10));

 % get style sheet info
 snam='foo'; % The name of your style file (NO extension)
 s=hgexport('readstyle',snam);

 %apply style sheet info
 fnam='myfig.jpeg'; % your file name
 s.Format = 'jpeg'; %I needed this to make it work but maybe you wont.
 hgexport(gcf,fnam,s);
```

And in your current folder should be a file called "myfig.jpeg" that is your figure with the export settings you made in "foo". If you want to see the style file options, type `s` into the command line. It should be a struct like this with all your export settings in it.

```
s = 

            Version: '1'
             Format: 'jpeg'
            Preview: 'none'
              Width: 'auto'
             Height: 'auto'
              Units: 'points'
              Color: 'rgb'
         Background: 'w'
      FixedFontSize: '10'
     ScaledFontSize: 'auto'
           FontMode: 'scaled'
        FontSizeMin: '8'
     FixedLineWidth: '1'
    ScaledLineWidth: 'auto'
           LineMode: 'scaled'
       LineWidthMin: '2'
           FontName: 'Wingdings'
         FontWeight: 'auto'
          FontAngle: 'auto'
       FontEncoding: 'latin1'
            PSLevel: '2'
           Renderer: 'auto'
         Resolution: 'auto'
       LineStyleMap: 'none'
         ApplyStyle: '0'
             Bounds: 'loose'
           LockAxes: 'on'
             ShowUI: 'on'
       SeparateText: 'off'
```

Comment: Nice. I had no idea hgexport did that.

Comment: I just googled for a solution like this only to find I had submitted this question a long time ago, and somehow didn't see that anyone had posted answers.   It works perfectly!

Comment: this solution works only if you want to save the plot as am image (png, jpg, eps, ...) but if you just want to apply the style to the figure itself, the matlab-command `hgexport(gcf,'temp_dummy','mystyle','applystyle', true);` (see `SDF` package solution below) does work.

Comment: @kromuchi, what do you replace 'temp_dummy' with to use the native matlab solution?

Comment: you don't have to replace it at all, as it is really just a dummy variable/string. I just recovered that from the `SDF` package (from Matlab Central) recommended by Zubair (see below) because I was curious how this `SDF` package solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following "SDF" package from MATLAB central. It is just one line command. Put this sdf.m file in your path. Here is an example.

```
figure;
hold on;
plot(rand(1,100));
plot(rand(1,100), 'r');
grid on;
box on;
sdf('mystyle');          %"mystyle" is the name of export style
```

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24807-sdf-set-the-figure

Comment: the command `sdf('mystyle')` can be replaced with the build-in matlab command `hgexport(gcf,'temp_dummy','mystyle','applystyle', true);`

Answer (score 0):

Not easily possible.

When you save a style from the Export Setup dialog, the relevant information gets saved into a text file in the MATLAB preferences directory. If you type `cd(fullfile(prefdir, 'ExportSetup'))` you can see them. The Export Setup dialog does a bunch of stuff that you can't easily access with those files when you create, apply and save new styles.

In theory you could read and parse those files yourself and apply the style programmatically, but I don't know if you'll find it worth the effort.

You might find it easier to create a plot, apply any changes and formatting you need, and then auto-generate a new command (`File->Generate Code` from the Figure menu). You could then just call that command instead of your regular plotting command, and have your figure set up to your requirements.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
exportsetupdlg;
fig=gcf;
fig.ExportsetupWindow.selectstylebutton.setSelectedItem('Your setting name');
fig.ExportsetupWindow.stylebutton.doClick();
fig.ExportsetupWindow.loadstylebutton.doClick();
fig.ExportsetupWindow.applybutton.doClick();
fig.ExportsetupWindow.closebutton.doClick();
```

This code after any figure drawings will open export setting dialog and change to set style and close.